# How to update mysql data using django?

Tags: python, mysql, django

How to update mysql data through django? I am not getting any error also.

> views.py

```
def update_db_data(request):
    conn = MySQLdb.connect(host= "localhost", user="test_user", passwd="test_pwd",db="myproject")
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    try:
        cursor.execute("UPDATE user SET user_name = 'test'")
        print("sucess")
        html = "<html><body>sucess</body></html>"
        conn.commit()
    except:
        print("fail")
        html = "<html><body>fail</body></html>"
        conn.rollback()
    conn.close()
    return HttpResponse(html)
```

Please tell me where is the problem in my code. 
How to do condition updates?

```
eg:- UPDATE user SET user_name = 'test' where id =2;
```

Comment: You can use Django-ORM for this simple query.Why not using it?

Answer (score 2):

Your table name is `user` but `USER` is a reserved keyword in mysql. Maybe that is causing the error.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html

Implement the finally block as follows and see if you are getting the error response.

```
def update_db_data(request):
    conn = MySQLdb.connect(host= "localhost", user="test_user", passwd="test_pwd",db="myproject")
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    try:
        cursor.execute("UPDATE user SET user_name = 'test'")
        print("sucess")
        html = "<html><body>sucess</body></html>"
        conn.commit()
    except:
        print("fail")
        html = "<html><body>fail</body></html>"
        conn.rollback()
    finally:
        conn.close()
        return HttpResponse(html)
```

Comment: USER is a keyword.. user is not a keyword. Same user table i am using to insert data in to table and selecting data from table there is no issues. updating data is the issue. Please help me with this

Comment: put the last 2 lines in `finally` block and see if you are getting error response.

Comment: Did you try to isolate the python code from django and ran it as a python script to see if it's working?

Answer (score 1):

For conditional query like this :

```
UPDATE user SET user_name = 'test' where id =2;
```

You can set default parameters for Database in settings.py file, like this:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'myproject',
        'USER': 'test_user',
        'PASSWORD': 'test_pwd',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
    }
}
```

And then use Django ORM for updating user_name,

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
def update_db_data(request):

    try:
        user_obj = User.objects.get( id = 2 )
        user_obj.user_name = "test"
        user_obj.save()
        print("sucess")
        html = "<html><body>sucess</body></html>"

    except:

        print("fail")
        html = "<html><body>fail</body></html>"

    return HttpResponse(html)
```